# How do I fix this "Internal Server Error" I keep getting?

Tags: https, http-status-code-500

I've been trying to create a site, sort of like https://feds.lol, https://guns.lol, or https://ebio.gg, but all has failed. A friend recommended https://phind.com, which has gotten me to where I am now. I have a basic site and when you go to a certain path it says "Internal Server Error" but I haven't found out why. I asked the AI to try and fix it, to no success. I went back to the original version I had and it still didn't work.

I asked the AI to try and fix it, to no success. I went back to the original version I had and it still didn't work.

Comment: You should consult your webserver's logs for the cause of the error. Relying on an AI model for this sort of task will likely be... frustrating.

Comment: Hello Kitty VPN, this is rather a question for https://serverfault.com/ .

Comment: I've been using replit to host it, and from what I can tell (which, granted, I don't know much about html) nothing seems to be wrong

Comment: File "/home/runner/Phind-Code-Snippet/app.py", line 95, in create_biolink
    return render_template('create_biolink.html')

that is the only thing I can find in the logs